# c++ error: expected unqualified-id before '[' token

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm trying to make a simple game in c++, I'm almost complete but I keep running into this error. I'm sure these are syntax errors, I'm just not sure on how to fix them.

```
Board::Board()
{
    side = 6;
    Piece[][] spaces = new Piece[6][6];
    for (int row = 00; row < side; ++row)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < side; ++column)
        {
            spaces[row][column] = new blankPiece;
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is what eclipse is saying:**

```
..\Board.cpp: In constructor 'Board::Board()':
..\Board.cpp:13:7: error: expected unqualified-id before '[' token
..\Board.cpp:18:30: error: no match for 'operator=' in '((Board*)this)->Board::spaces[row][column] = (operator new(8u), (<statement>, ((blankPiece*)<anonymous>)))'
..\/Piece.h:14:1: note: candidate is: Piece& Piece::operator=(const Piece&)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [\[C++\] How do I declare a 2d array using new?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/c-how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-using-new)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is illegal:

```
Piece[][]
```

C++ does not store a 2-dimensional array as an array of pointers, but rather a flat series of subarrays. Therefore all but the last bound must be specified.

Also, `new` is unnecessary and undesirable if the array size is fixed. Simply use this.

```
Piece spaces[6][6]; // that's all!
```

Finally, the entries in the array are `Piece` objects, not pointers. Initializing them to `blankPiece` (whatever that is) should be unnecessary because the default (no-argument) constructor `Piece::Piece()` should initialize the object to the blank state. To reinitialize, use

```
myPiece = Piece();
```

---

If the array size is variable, best practice is to use `std::vector` instead of `new[]`. Here is the most common approach to two-dimensional `vector`:

```
typedef vector< vector< Piece > > Board;
Board spaces( 6, vector< Piece >( 6 ) );
```

That is a little ugly, and you might look into alternatives like `boost::multi_array`.

Comment: thanks a lot! that worked, I know I'm not supposed to use arrays, but I'm still not familiar with vectors as I am somewhat new to c++, I will definitely try vector alternative in a copy of this game to get a good grasp. I will also check out boost multi_array for future. Everything worked out pretty good, just gotta make a few minor fixes and test the game. Once again, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's this line: `Piece[][] spaces = new Piece[6][6];`

That's not how C++ constructs type names for arrays.  Try:

```
Piece (*spaces)[6] = new Piece[6][6];
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do `Piece[][]`, try:

```
Piece** spaces = new Piece*[6];
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    spaces[i] = new Piece[6];
}
```

Or use [`boost::multi_array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use just this

> Piece spaces[6][6];

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare an array with more than 1 unknown dimension. Use pointers or `std::vector` instead.

Also, you allocate memory which you keep in a local variable `spaces` that disappears once you're out of the function, it should be a class member.